# xrandr doesn't correctly configure GeChic 1503H external HDMI monitor

Tags: linux, xrandr

[UPDATE 12 Oct:  I have determined that it is not related to the laptop/GeForce hardware.  The issue is related to nouveau/nvidia drivers.  I get the same behavior described below on both the GeChic panel and an ASUS LCD monitor.  Both or on HDMI.  For behavior jump down to the updated portion. ]

I have a GeChic 1503H external HDMI monitor which works correctly from Windows 10.   However, if I use xrandr, the monitor seems to be configure with the incorrect refresh rate - maybe it's something else??  This is a linux installation with 5.2.0 kernel, using the kernel's *nouveau driver*.

The device is found by xrandr:

```
> HDMI-1-3 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)   
> 1920x1080     60.00 +  59.96    50.00    59.94    59.93     
> 1920x1080i    69.09    60.00    50.00    59.94      1680x1050    
> 59.95    59.88      1440x1080     59.99      1400x1050     59.98
```

However after executing:

> xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --auto --output HDMI-1-3 --auto

or

> xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --auto --output HDMI-1-3 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00

The screen is activated, and appears to be a mirror of the main eDP1 screen as I can see the blurry cursor image moving.  Here is a picture of the resulting screen:

[image]

EDID information per request:

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface

        Performing real mode VBE call
        Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
        Function unsupported
        Call failed

        VBE version 0
        VBE string at 0x0 "Partial Read... Try again
```

If anyone can suggest something to try I'd be glad to do so.

**27 Oct, Some additional tests/info.**

Blacklisting nouveau, after installing NVIDIA's 430.50 and rebooting the primary display starts, however once the video driver is loaded, the primary eDSP1 laptop display blanks out, and the GeChic panel turns on.   This made realize that I thought my external ASUS 24" panel was dead ... however when I connect it to the laptop with NVIDIA's driver (rather than nouveau as I had always been doing) the panel works fine.  But, also, eDSP1 is blank on the laptop.

xrandr with NVIDIA's driver:

> Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
>   HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y >axis) 293mm x 1
>   65mm
>     1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
>     1680x1050     59.95
>     1600x900      60.00
>   DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: I think it's a driver issue: what driver are you using? for which graphic card?

Comment: @dirdi I'm using the nouveau driver as of kernel 5.2.0.

Comment: Any interesting output to `dmesg`?

Comment: @LucasRamage no, dmesg has nothing.  I described different behavior with the NVIDIA driver.  This DELL laptop's external HDMI port isn't what I was expecting.

Comment: 1. So, it looks definitively like a *driver* issue? 2. What do you mean with your HDMI port? 3. please add laptop model/hardware

Comment: @mattia.b89, it's a Dell G7 17 7790.   I'm not positive it's only a driver issue, but it's definitely one of or combination of driver/hardware design.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: @Daniel Any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a *driver* issue!
and I bet it will be fixed in the near future because your hardware is really, ***really*** new:
Intel Core 8th gen + NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070

Comment: htanks for the confirmatian.  Now I sit and wait :(